# duplex printing by HP1108 using HPLIP

Tags: printing, hp, hplip, duplex-printing

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my system and I use HP p1108 laserjet printer. Before Ubuntu, I was using the same printer with Windows 10. The duplex printing(Printing on both sides of the page) was supported there, but is grayed out in Ubuntu. Is there any possible fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to install proprietary hp plugin with `hp-plugin` to use some of the advanced options, e.g. duplex printing.

Once the binary plugin installed as described [on hplip page](http://hplipopensource.com/node/309), Printers > HP_Color_LaserJet_MFP_M477fdw > Properties > Installed Options will show new "Duplex Unit" option with a checkbox. Under Properties > Printer Options > Two-Sided now allows to select "Long-Edge Binding".