# HPLIP / HP Device Manager: "Print job has completed", but nothing happens (HP Laserjet Professional P 1102w)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, printing, hp, hplip

1. When I connect `HP Laserjet Professional P 1102w` to my `XPS13` with `Ubuntu 18.04`, HP Device Manager recognizes the printer and tells me that the `printer is idle` (I have also installed the proprietary hp plugin).
2. Then I click `Print Test Page` and it tells me that it `Started a print job` and then `Print job has completed`, but my printer does NOT do anything!

[image]

Another thing that struck me is that `ls /dev/usb` outputs `lp0`, but as soon as I start to print a document it shows me `ls: cannot access '/dev/usb': No such file or directory` until I reconnect the printer device.

What could be wrong? The printer works just fine on my Mac as usual, what can I do to make it run on Ubuntu? I am struggeling for days with this problem now!

**EDIT:** I have already installed the needed proprietary binary plugin for my printer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [duplex printing by HP1108 using HPLIP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/798460/duplex-printing-by-hp1108-using-hplip). According to [HPLIP page](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/binary_plugin.html) you need to install proprietary binary plugin for your printer.

Comment: I have already installed the plugin. What else can I do to make this work? Who is responsible for this? Can I call Canonical or HP to ask them to help me with their not working software?

Comment: @saitam If you have a payable support contract you can call Canonical, otherwise you should call HP. (with the free version you cannot call Canonical)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 18.04.1 and hplip 3.18.7. Installing hplip 3.18.6 solved the problem.

My HP LaserJet M1132 Multifunction Printer is detected and configured properly with hplip 3.18.7, and `hp-check` shows no errors nor warnings, but a Cups test page stays in the queue with state "Filter failed". In `/var/log/cups/error_log` I see:

```
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] prnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 644: DEBUG: SHIVA inside the while loopprnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 648: DEBUG: imageProcessorStartPage failed result = 2
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] STATE: -media-empty-error,media-jam-error,hplip.plugin-error,cover-open-error,toner-empty-error,other
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] PAGE: 1 1\r
D [29/Aug/2018:17:42:31 -0300] [Job 13166] PID 3566 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups) crashed on signal 11.
```

See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/1788706

You can [download hplip 3.18.6 from here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hplip/files/hplip/3.18.6/hplip-3.18.6.run/download), then install it as usual, with `sh hplip-3.18.6.run`. Don't install it as root, use the same user you used to log in (and be sure that user is in the `sudo` group).

If you find any problem during installation, specially downloading your printer driver, run `hp-plugin`.

Afterwards, running `hp-check` should show no errors (and preferably no warnings as well). Test your setup, e.g., by [printing a test job from Cups](http://localhost:631/printers/).

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life! What a bad update from HP!

Comment: Thanks so much !